# Modifying global variables in Objective-C blocks

Tags: ios, objective-c

So I have an instance function that takes in an `NSInteger` as a parameter; and in the function, I have a block.  I need to modify the `NSInteger` that gets passed into the function.  But it isn't a `__block` type.  How should I go about doing that?
The original function is too complicated so I'll just put a simplified version here...

```
//@interface
@property(nonatomic) NSInteger input; 
...

//@implementation
[self doThis:self.input];

-(void)doThis:(NSInteger)integer{
    [API doSomethingWithThisInteger:integer success:^(NSMutableDictionary *data){
        ...
    } failure:^(NSString *error){
        integer--;
    }
}
```

I know that I'm supposed to pass in a `__block` type variable but if I initialized a new one in the function (i.e. `__block NSInteger temp = integer`) and put `temp--` instead of `integer--` in the `failure` block, then `self.input` would remain the same since the initialization statement copies the value of `input` instead of referencing to it.  What should I do here?  Is there a way to make the new variable a reference to the variable I pass into the function?  Thanks!

---

**EDIT: solution to problem -** 
Used a global variable instead of a property -

```
@implementation
NSInteger input;
....
[self doThis:&input]; //sends in the address of the input
....
- (void)doThis:(NSInteger *)integer{ //takes the pointer of the input instead of its actual value so it gets referenced rather than getting copied
    [API doSomethingWithThisInteger:integer success:^(NSMutableDictionary *data){
    ...
} failure:^(NSString *error){
    *integer = *integer - 1; //dereference the pointer to get the value.
}
```

Comment: You can't do it like that. The parameter is passed by value. Any change to it inside the method is not reflected anywhere outside of the method.

Comment: @rmaddy but I have another method that takes in a `(UIScrollView *) scrollview` as an argument. I passed in `self.scrollview` and put something like `[scrollview addSubview...]` in that method and it worked?  Worked as in the UI got updated?

Comment: That's completely different. It's one thing to call methods on an object pointer passed into the method. It's a completely different things to return an updated value for a primitive type that was passed by value.

Comment: @rmaddy ohh okay I always thought properties were supposed to be treated as objects...

Comment: Properties has nothing to do with it. In this case you are dealing with the primitive type of `NSInteger`. You need a completion block that can pass back the new value to the caller. Then the caller can do what it needs to with the updated value.

Comment: ehh sry i didn't know what i was saying before (got pretty pissed by the guy trying to "answer" my question) no we dont treat properties as objects yeah what i'd always thought was that all properties were passed by reference in instance functions...

Comment: In Objective-C, all parameters are passed by value no matter their type. Of course with object pointers, it is the pointer that is passed by value.

Comment: @rmaddy yes that does ring a bell!  Thanks!!

Comment: @rmaddy Can I use double asterisks when I pass in the parameter and dereference it in the block?

Comment: With a primitive type you need one asterisk. With pointers you need two asterisks. But in this case, I don't know if it will work due to your block (presumably) being called asynchronously.

Comment: @rmaddy I ended up solving the problem using an extra asterisk.  As you said everything in Obj-C is passed by value so it'd make sense to pass in the pointer to the original pointer right?  I created a global variable (not a property) under `@implementation`, had the function `doThis` take in `(NSInteger *) integer` and put [self doThis:&(input)] instead of [self doThis:self.input] and it worked just fine !  And of course I dereferenced the variable using `*integer` inside the function.

Comment: *Correction - "the pointer to the original pointer" only works for objects haha, now we're dealing with a primitive type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Objective-C, like C, passes everything by value. It welds objects on top of C by putting them on the heap and referring to them by pointer. So what you're passing around isn't the object itself, it's the address of the object. The address itself is passed by value. But if someone knows the address, they can go to the heap and modify the object.

Your input to `doThis:` is a parameter, `integer`. So when calling that method what will have happened is:

1. whatever you wrote where the parameter should be will be evaluated and, if necessary, implicitly cast to `NSInteger';
2. a copy of that `NSInteger` will be supplied to the method;
3. having received its own copy, `integer` is now equivalent to a local variable for the method.

So e.g. you could do:

```
[object doThis:8];
```

The `8` is copied into what is effectively a local variable within `doThis:`, so you can modify `integer` all you like regardless of the fact that you passed in a constant.

If you want `doThis:` to be able to modify the integer then you need to supply a pointer to it. And once you have that you should have no problem using that pointer inside a block. The pointer itself will be captured but, as when passing a pointer into a method, if you modify what the pointer points to then that will effect everybody else that looks there.

Comment: Would it make any sense to you if I did something like `(NSInteger)&this.input`?  Supplying a pointer address :$

Comment: The point of properties is that you don't assume anything about the storage; most often they're modelled directly by instance variables but are not necessarily so. They may be computed, or converted to and from storage. As a result, `&this.input` doesn't give you a pointer to the storage — there's no way to do that through a property. You probably want to get `doThis:` to produce a value then set it to `this.input` (umm, if by 'input' you kind of also mean 'output')

Comment: Oh sorry about the this i meant self by that but year you're right there's no way to access the pointer of a property so I ended up solving the problem using an extra asterisk.  I created a global variable (not a property) under `@implementation`, had the function `doThis` take in `(NSInteger *) integer` and put [self doThis:&(input)] instead of [self doThis:self.input] and it worked just fine !  And of course I dereferenced the variable using `*integer` inside the function.

Answer (score 1):

You have to give a block some reference to variable to modify. By calling `doThis:` you pass an integer by value (not by reference), so failure block gets effectively just a copy of `integer` value - so original variable has no chance to get modified.

The same is valid for `__block NSInteger temp = integer` - temp gets a copy of an `integer`. Block can modify `temp`, however it's just a copy of `integer` - so no chance to change the original value.

To get the value changed, use:

```
-(void)doThis
{
    [API doSomethingWithSuccess:^(NSMutableDictionary *data)
    {
        ...
    } 
    failure:^(NSString *error)
    {
        self.input--;
    }
}
```

This way you get a reference to input via `self`. However, it's considered bad in ARC environment because `self` gets impliciltly captured by the block and this may lead to retain cycle. So, the best way is create weak reference to self and let it get captured by the block:

```
-(void)doThis
{
    __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
    [API doSomethingWithSuccess:^(NSMutableDictionary *data)
    {
        ...
    } 
    failure:^(NSString *error)
    {
        weakSelf.input--;
    }
}
```

P.S. Your question effectively discloses, that you have no idea, how it works - pointers, passing parameters by value/by reference, ObjC blocks etc. You should get more theoretical knowledge about your programming language to avoid such questions in future.

Comment: I know that using your method would've worked because that's exactly what I did at the beginning.  But in MY case there are multiple `self.inputs` (they are being used similarly e.g. self.input1, self.input2).  I just want to make this method dynamic.  It's not like I don't understand anything about pointers or anything, no need to be mean about this?  I know what I'm doing.

Comment: Your discussion with rmaddy in comments to your question effectively disclosures the same thing. If you have an array of `input`'s, pass the appropriate index to API call. If you have many properties, like  `input1`, `input2`, `input3` - you are using bad model. There are many solutions here, like run-time property set, creating separate function calls for each parameter and many others. You will see all options yourself, when you will understand what the pointer is.

Comment: Are you here to answer a question or to insult people who ask questions?